# SD card will not format to FAT32 using command line or formatter tools

Tags: video, sd-card, fat32

I have an SD card that was being used in my dashcam in my car. I ran out of space while it was filming and the file became corrupted. Now, I can't format SD card no matter what I do. If I delete the files from the SD card using my computer, they just come back when I plug in the SD card into the camera.

1. I have tried the built in `Format` tool that is seen when right-clicking the SD card in the File Explorer. I get the error message `Windows was unable to complete the format`.
2. I have also tried changing the `Read-Only` attribute from the the command line in hopes of then being able to delete all files and maybe successfully formatting the SD card but also did not work:

```
attrib -r D:\DCIM\VIDEO\*.*
attrib -r D:\DCIM\VIDEO
```

This was me clearing the `Read Only attribute` for the folder that contains the video files and all of the files inside it. This did nothing. The read only attribute was still there in the properties after this.

3. I tried using `disk part` like this to clear the read only attribute:

```
attributes disk clear readonly
```

4. I have tried other software such as `SD card Formatter` and that also does nothing.

I have literally ran out of options, how in the world can I delete all of these files and format this SD card so that I can use it again??

Comment: The card is dead. Replace it.

Comment: Make sure the read only switch on the card is off.